# Does anyone know where to get the [Stack Overflow Search] Visual Studio extension?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

On my client workstation, my installation of VS2012 came with a stack overflow integrated search bar that sits alongside the quick launch.  It looks like this:

[image: stack overflow]

The problem with this is that it is very cool, I want it added to my personal machine, but no one knows how it got onto my machine or where to find it.  I know this question hasn't been asked on stack overflow before because visual studio told me so, included in the image below

[image: stack overflow]

The only extensions that I currently have installed to visual studio are included in the screenshot below and are consistent with all of my colleagues' installs. That's why it's a bit puzzling for me to have this while they don't.

[image: stack overflow]

Does anyone else have this? 
Where did you get it?

Comment: Oh..hey. This question showed up immediately in the integrated Stack Overflow search.  
http://i665.photobucket.com/albums/vv20/Tombstone67/vs-stack-overflow-question_zps51b7946c.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the Web Search extension:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a0c66cb5-5d6d-46ab-b169-273dec17eb24

or maybe VS Commands:

http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/blog

Comment: I thought it might be the Web Search Extension, but it doesn't seem to be.  First, I don't have the Web Search Extension installed; second, the Web Search Extension seems to be driven by a context menu. What I have is an everpresent, integrated Stack Overflow search bar

Comment: Then VSCommands is what you're looking for.  These are the main two that are out there.

Comment: Ok. I have VSCommands (It's listed in the bottom screenshot of my post) I installed it earlier for VS2013 (before I posted the question), but I wasn't prompted to restart visual studio. When I shutdown and restarted, my [Stack Overflow] integrated search bar showed up.